# Joomla3.x component curl JHttpTransportCurl

Tags: php, curl, joomla3.0, joomla-component

I'm developing a component require to use a management software api, which is using curl to accessing the data in that software.

However, it seems joomla restrict the curl access, because the api working fine without the joomla. When in joomla it show the error

```
 1 Curl error: Protocol " https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

after some research on google, i found joomla may only accept curl request sending from JHttpTransportCurl. Please advice relate tutorial or example of how to using JHttpTransportCurl  class.